# VS Code - combine snippets into one command

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Newbie question

Is there a way to combine multiple snippets into one command?

Example, I have Powershell extension added and I know how to insert "Comment-Help" and "Parameter-Block" snippets individually, but I'm curious if there is a way to combine snippets into a single command such as *New-Scirpt

Comment: using your example snippets: what are there current definitions and what do you expect of the combined snippet

Comment: Edit your question to show your two snippets that you already have.

Comment: What I ended up doing was writing a custom "user snippet" which copy-paste the individual snippets from the Powershell Extension that I was interested in.

If there is another way to do this without writing a user snippet, I would appreciate the guidance. 

Thanks